# bracket: How to ignore exceptions from the "release resource" function?

Tags: exception, haskell

The current behaviour of `bracket` causes the following expression to throw `inside release`. However, this is behaviour doesn't work for my use-case.

Which standard Haskell function would throw the original exception raised by the core action, i.e. it will throw `inside action`?

```hs
bracket 
  (pure ()) -- acquire resource
  (const $ UnliftIO.throwString "inside release") -- release resource
  (const $ UnliftIO.throwString "inside action") -- action which uses the resource
```

**Why do I need this?** In my case the "resource" is running an SQL statement which will effect the SQL connection as long as the session exists. I want to make sure that the effect of that SQL statement is always undone via "release resource". However, if the "core action" itself has an SQL error, then "release resource" always fails with `current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block` which completely gobbles-up the core/underlying exception thrown by the action.

Comment: Perhaps you could have two nested brackets. An outer one for the "core action" and an inner one for the SQL statement. If the allocation of the outer bracket fails, the inner one won't get executed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me you could just catch the error inside the release function:

```
bracket 
  (pure ())
  (const $
    catch 
      (UnliftIO.throwString "inside release") 
      (\(_ :: StringException) -> pure ()))
  (const $ UnliftIO.throwString "inside action")
```

Comment: Yes - that's a solution, but I thought I was missing some standard Haskell library function here.

Comment: @SaurabhNanda I think your situation where the exception is (presumably) safe to ignore is quite special and not worth adding as a special library function.

Comment: Do you know if there is a standard pattern in Haskell to preserve the original exception and add another exception to it and then throw both of them together? And how would one apply that in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You can try `bracket` from [safe-exception](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-exceptions-0.1.7.4/docs/Control-Exception-Safe.html#v:bracket). Technically it [doesn't specify](https://github.com/fpco/safe-exceptions#exceptions-in-cleanup-code) the exact behavior in case of an exception in the cleanup action, but it practice does the right thing, i.e. it prefers the exception from the inside action when both a synchronous.

Not directly related, but you are doing something wrong with your release action if it fails with `current transaction is aborted` error. I assume you are using postresql, where you are not allowed to use your database connection if the previous statement failed. You are probably trying to rollback a transaction, but you should just close the connection right away.